# Need a way to set custom axisLabel & axisTick on the apache echarts

Tags: axis-labels, echarts, gauge, apache-echarts

Currently the Gauge chart from Echarts only allow to configure **splitNumber** but I need a way to only show certain **axisLabels** and **axisTicks** like the example below, I tried to use **formatter** in **axisLabel** but I can only filter the labels not limit the ticks.

Current :-
[image]

Required :-
[image]
[image]

https://github.com/apache/echarts/issues/16437

Comment: i have the same issue, if you got resolve help me pleaseee

Comment: @sergioBertolazzo I haven't got any solution yet